# Process printing doublesided

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I have a code where i am printing word document.
I have decided on using print process as i need to print from command line.

In the sample document there is a section with picure that has modified margins by user.

> How do i set it up to print doublesided?

**my code so far:**

```
            Process printJob = new Process();

            printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
            printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
            printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            printJob.StartInfo.FileName = path;

            printJob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
            printJob.Start();
```

Comment: You can't.  Use the classes in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i set it up to print doublesided?

Just setup 2 pages.  The print if setup to support printing on both sides of a single piece of paper will simply do that.

**Why on earth are you using a Process to print a word document?**

Comment: because i want to run it from command line and found this is easiest way of doing this. Unless you have better solution, in which case i am all ears:)

Comment: What is the "print if setup"?

Comment: @Blaise - I honestly forget.  I was basically telling the author to write code to do duplex printing.

Answer (score 0):

> For Word Printing and to change Printer settings as Double sided use
>   [System.Drawing.Printing.Printdocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx)

Using Process Will not give you much setting options but you can try

> to change registry settings for Word on Server/Client machine to
>   always use double side print - that will be a question for Micrsoft
>   Word Q/A I guess